# hibernate vs weblogic antlr version

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, antlr, weblogic12c

We have a problem with migrating our `j2ee ear` application from `weblogic 12.1.1` to `weblogic 12.2.1`. We use `hibernate 5.2.10.Final` as a jpa provider and package it into the ear.

Hibernate has an implicit dependency of `antlr 2.7.7`, so the ear contains this jar too. But weblogic has internally on its classpath an `antlr 3.2`

We made its classloader prefer the contents of our ear, which is `antlr 2.7.7`, but this way weblogic throws an exception at some JMS method calls, where we use a JMS expression filtering for correlation id. So this way we lose an application server feature we use.

If we use `antlr 3.2` instead, would it be a problem for hibernate? Or what other options we have to use both functionality (hibernate and weblogic)? In eclipselink I checked, that it is solved by the way of repackaging antlr to some org.eclipselink... Is there a hibernate version available like this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is old, but I had a similar problem. In our case it was the scope "provided" that made the problem.

Seems in Hibernate 6.0 they will upgrade the antlr4.
http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/6.0/